# Can I call multiple operation contracts when ConcurrencyMode is Single

Tags: wcf, concurrency, operationcontract, servicebehavior

I have a WCF service with 3 operation contracts. I set `[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]` for this service. My basic doubt is can I able to call all the 3 service at a time or only one contracts can be called at once. Please can any one give a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency mode has scope for instance context mode. If you set `ConcurrencyMode` to `Single` you just tell WCF that each service instance can handle only one concurrent request - `Single` is also default value for `ConcurrencyMode`.

Unless you configure `InstanceContextMode` to `Single` as well (= you will make your service singleton) your service host will spawn new service instance either for each request (stateless bindings like `BasicHttpBinding` or `WebHttpBinding`) or for each connected proxy (statefull bindings like `NetTcpBinding`, `NamedPipeBinding` and some configurations of `WsHttpBinding`). In the former case `ConcurrencyMode` doesn't have any effect because each service instance is used only to handle single request = requests from any number of clients can be handled concurrently. In later case `ConcurrencyMode.Single` tells that requests from single client proxy are handled in sequential order but requests from multiple client proxies can be handled concurrently. Each exposed contract requires separate endpoint and each consumed endpoint on a client requires separate proxy instance so proxy for each contract will have separate service instance in this case.

With your current configuration only service throttling controls how many concurrent clients can consume your service.

Once you set `InstanceContextMode` to `Single` as well you will indeed have the service which will be able to handle only single request at one time. The number of implemented contracts doesn't matter because all contracts exposed in endpoints on single service are in this case handled by single service instance which accepts only one concurrent request.